# C++ Creating an Array with a variable as length generates randomly sized array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am recreating the string class using char arrays. My problem is, when I allocate memory for a larger array, it generates an array that is completely the wrong size.

For example:

```
int allocated = 4;
char * reservedString = new char[allocated];
cout << strlen(reservedString);
```

Instead of creating a character array of size 4, reservedString points to a character array with 14 spots containing random characters.

[image]

This is what the debug shows me. Reserved string is now the wrong size with a bunch of random characters in it. When I try to use strcpy or strcpy_s it is writing memory out of bounds because the new array sizes are wrong.

How can I create a char array with an unknown length, which is provided by a variable, that is right size.
I can not use the std::string class or std::vector.

Comment: You want to use `std::vector` or `std::string`.

Comment: I would if I could but this is for a class project and I can not use vectors or string, only arrays.

Comment: Read here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/. The function searches for the termination character. Your string is uninitialized.

Comment: You don't initialize your array, so it contains random garbage. As noted by Chiel, `strlen` will search for null-terminator, it can't know how many bytes you allocated.

Comment: Would it be appropriate for my code to do this: reservedString[allocated] = '\0'; so that when I create the array its the correct size?

Comment: No, because you're writing one character past the end of your allocated memory, and also having `strlen` attempt to read the uninitialized values in the middle of the array is undefined behavior (as far as we know there could just happen to be a null character there). You need to properly initialize your entire array. Why do you need to find the size of a newly allocated array using `strlen` anyway? If you aren't going to put a null-terminated string into it you should be keeping track of it's size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating an object with the new operator, your data remains not initialized. The code you provide is basically an array of bytes.

The documentation about `strlen` says:

> computes the length of the string str up to, but not including the terminating null character.

There is no null terminator here.

You should do:

```
int allocated = 4;
char * reservedString = new char[allocated]();
```

This will initialize your array and set all the elements  to `\0`

Comment: Because every element is set to a terminating null character, strlen will return 0 but I can keep track of the size myself. In terms of memory, even though strlen is returning 0 because the first character is now a null terminating character, does it still reserve 4 bytes of memory?

Comment: @EmptyStuff you are right, the memory has been properly allocated.  Now you can check the size properly each time you modify the string, you just need to track the size.

Comment: @EmptyStuff Yes. `strlen` gives the length of the null-terminated string, which can be different than the size of the array used to store the string.

Comment: @mohabouje Or just properly null-terminate it. The string functions should handle the rest as long as the array is big enough.

Comment: @FeiXiang could you elaborate on what you mean by properly null-terminate it.

Comment: @EmptyStuff Make sure it ends in a null character? It's now that hard. String literals should be automatically null-terminated, and the input functions will also null-terminate the string. You should only have to worry about this when you're creating a string by setting each of the characters individually, in which case just set the character past the last one to null and make sure your array is big enough to store the extra character.

Comment: "the memory has been properly allocated" - very likely, but not confirmed.  You need to check the allocation result.  Consider adding a line  "assert ( nullptr != reservedString );" after new, and before you initialize;

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` expects a null-terminated string, which means a string that ends in a null character (`\0`). You're passing to it a pointer pointing to newly allocated memory, which contains uninitialized values and reading it causes undefined behavior. So when `strlen` searches for a null character in order to determine the length of the string, stuff is going to go wrong.

You cannot determine the size of an array given only a pointer to it unless you know it's going to be terminated by a null character or something similar. So either properly initialize the array with a null-terminated string or keep track of the length yourself.